# customer as a partner magento error

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I just implemented a module from WebKul Customer as a partner, but I am having a problem with this area of the code. Can anyone please point me to the area that needs fixing?

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('nickname', $value)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('nin' => $customer_id));
```

This gives the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /home/xxx/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

I am new to Magento, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This module costs $99. Surely if you have a problem with it you would speak to WebKul before trying to fix it yourself? *Edit* I see you have contacted them also ...

Comment: Hello Still if you any trouble with magento customer as partner module please add a support ticket . we will help you out for sure http://webkul.com/ticket/index.php Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the setup script for the module did not install? To diagnose, do the following:

1. Verify the module version in its *config.xml* file and check that the **version** and **data_version** match this value in the `core_resource` table.
2. Verify that the attributes are present in `eav_attribute` table by searching for the attribute code.

Comment: hello ben the problem is that the module is not the type you install via magento_connect you do it via ftp and everything works fine to the point i want to change a customer's nickname from the front end on the dashboard but could not perform this operation due to this problem and to verify the config.xml now is also a problem for the thanks for responding benmarks but how do i add attribute to the eav_attribute table.

Comment: This is an issue for the extension vendor. Their extension (whether installed via connect or direct file transfer) *should* run upgrade scripts to add & configure these attributes. To fix yourself, look at any core EAV module's upgrade script folder (e.g. *Mage/Customer/sql/customer/*).

Comment: thanks ben this 2 sql queries solved the problem after a long time of searching. INSERT INTO `tbl_mage_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, 

`attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, 

`frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, 

`is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES (NULL, '1', 'nickname', NULL, NULL, 

'static', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '0', '0', NULL, '0', NULL);
ALTER TABLE `tbl_mage_customer_entity` ADD `nickname` VARCHAR( 100 ) NULL ;

Comment: Aaaand it's broken. That's why you should use setup scripts + the correct setup class. See [`Mage_Tax`'s install script](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Tax/sql/tax_setup/install-1.6.0.0.php#L243) - also, note that many of those values are not be stored in `eav_attribute` - they are stored in `catalog_eav_attribute`

Comment: yes as you figured been it was broken from the people i bought it from it should have been done in the setup scripts which was not portable with databases with prefixes so that's how i found my way around the problem anyway. cos i av to refactor a lot of the table creation and sql operation codes. thanks.